# Passing a parameter from main report to drillthrough SQL Server Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to restrict what users can view based on the branch that they work in.  I have it working on my main report but I want to pass the branch parameter from my main report to a drillthrough subreport.  How can I do this in Report Builder 3.0?  Thank you.

Comment: by drill through sub-report, are you sending them to a completely different report, or is this a sub-report inside of the main report?  these are significantly different ways of consuming the report and passing parameters is different

Comment: This is a completely different report that we are using as a drillthrough subreport from the main report.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameter via the [url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx).

Example:

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008
```

Here we're passing the report parameter **ReportMonth** the value 3 and **ReportYear** with 2008

Comment: @donald.Dougherty in the report, build the url as a string and place the variable in the url.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using a URL, you'd need the same parameters in both reports.

- Go to the properties of where you want the drill-through to occur. 
  Go to Action
- Select 'Go to Report', specify the report directory (this can be flat files or via the report server). Think this can also be a URL but I am not certain.
- Select 'Add'. In the Name field, you want to put the parameter name of the parameter in the drill-through report, in the 'Value' field you want to enter the parameter of the report that you're currently in.

If you don't want the user changing this parameter, in the drill-through report, you can simply hide this parameter in the drill-through report.

This is by far the easiest way of doing what you require I believe. Hope this helps if you're still struggling.